# Use twig to style a specific block (unformated list)

Tags: blocks, 8, theming

I have a block showing a unformated List of fields. Now I would like to use twig to style that block.

I am able to use `block--views-block--blockname-block.html.twig` to do the outer styling. But I could not get the fields out of the content.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand what you mean...

Do you want to customize the fields that appear in your block?? If so, Drupal normally provides you with available twig hooks you could use. Yours would probably be *field.html.twig*.

Exemple : you can customize a menu with *menu.html.twig* and then customize the links in that menu with *links.html.twig*

Comment: Thanks. Actually I try to override the `views-view-unformatted.html.twig` template with a specific only showing up on one node but it seems like it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. I've already overwritten form templates to add a template suggestion that included the form id. Here's the code :

```
function hugo_theme_suggestions_form_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
    if (isset($variables['element']) && isset($variables['element']['#type']) && $variables['element']['#type'] == 'form') {
        $original_theme_hook = $variables['theme_hook_original'];
        $suggestions[] = $original_theme_hook . '__' . str_replace('-', '_', $variables['element']['#id']);
    }
}
```

Maybe you could reuse this piece of code changing the form by the view, something like `YOURTHEME_theme_suggestions_view_alter`